# closure-compiler ant task fails when compiling jquery

Tags: jquery, ant, google-closure-compiler

I am using `closure-compiler`, to to make a test, I compile a `jquery.js` in ant like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="test" default="compile">

<taskdef name="jscomp" classname="com.google.javascript.jscomp.ant.CompileTask" classpath="${basedir}/closure/compiler.jar"></taskdef>
<target name="compile">

<jscomp compilationlevel="simple" debug="false" output="${basedir}/min.js">



    <sources dir="${basedir}/../test/war/ui/jquery">
        <file name="jquery.js">
    </file></sources>

</jscomp>
```

And the build fails with an compilation error. However, when I change the `debug` to `true`, the ant build is successful. What's the issue here?

Comment: You need to post the compilation error for this to be answered.